# How can I make a dropdown menu to change theme using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to make a dropdown menu like thing to change theme of the website.
I have created a dropdown menu in Navbar.js file

```
<form>
  <select id="dropdown" onChange={changedEvent} >
    <option value="blue" >Blue Theme</option>
    <option value="green" >Green Theme</option>
    <option value="red" >Red Theme</option>
  </select>
  </form>
```

which I am handling using changedEvent function

```
function changedEvent()
  {
    switch(document.getElementById("dropdown").value)
    {
      case "blue":
        props.setTheme("blue");
        break;
      case "green":
          props.setTheme("green");
          break;

          case "red":
          props.setTheme("red");
           break;

    }
  }
```

and This code is not working. It only changes it to blue color which is default when toggling the switch.

This is Navbar.js file

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default function Navbar(props) {

  function changedEvent()
  {
    switch(document.getElementById("dropdown").value)
    {
      case "blue":
        props.setTheme("blue");
        break;
      case "green":
          props.setTheme("green");
          break;

          case "red":
          props.setTheme("red");
           break;

    }
  }
  return (
    <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
    <div className="container-fluid">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">{props.title}</a>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="/">About</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div className={`form-check form-switch text-${props.mode==='light'?'dark':'light'}`}>
  <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" onClick={props.toggleMode}/>
  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Dark Mode</label>
  <form>
  <select id="dropdown" onChange={changedEvent} >
    <option value="blue" >Blue Theme</option>
    <option value="green" >Green Theme</option>
    <option value="red" >Red Theme</option>
  </select>
  </form>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
  )
}


Navbar.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  setTheme: PropTypes.func,
};
```

This is my main app.js react file

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import TextForm from './components/TextForm';
import About from './components/About';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [Mode, setMode] = useState('light'); //whether dark mode is enabled or not
  const [alert, setalert] = useState(null);
  const [Theme, setTheme] = useState("#063970");

  const handleThemeChange = (newTheme) => {
    setTheme(newTheme);
  };
  
  function showAlert(message,type)
  {
    setalert(
      {
        msg:message,
        type:type
      }
    )
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    setalert(null);
  }, 5000);

  

  const toggleMode = () => {
    switch (Mode) {
      case 'light':
        setMode('dark');
        
        showAlert(" Dark mode enabled","success")
        switch (Theme)
        {
          case 'blue':
            document.body.style.backgroundColor='#063970';
            break;
          case 'green':
            document.body.style.backgroundColor='#088a56';
            break;
          case 'red':
            document.body.style.backgroundColor='#8a0808';
            break;
          default:
          document.body.style.backgroundColor='#063970';
          break;
        }
        break;
      case 'dark':
        setMode('light');
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='white';
        showAlert(" Dark mode disabled","success")
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar  title="Fontify" mode={Mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} settTheme={handleThemeChange}/>
    <Alert alert={alert}/>

    <div className="container">
    <TextForm heading="Enter the text to analyse" mode={Mode}/>
    {/* <About/> */}
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 1. If you'd create a working example using codesandbox or a similar tool, it'd easier for us to help. 2. Navbar call `setTheme` but _app.js_ doesn't use it during the render. It's using it only when it calls `toggleMode` 3. A kindly advice, please don't interact with the DOM directly (e.g. `document.getElementById` and use the declarative way React offers.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements that might help:

1. Fix the typo: settTheme vs. setTheme

```js
<Navbar  title="Fontify" mode={Mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} setTheme={handleThemeChange}/>
```

2. Do something with `Theme`, after it has been changed. Currently, the state is only used within the toggle function.
3. Simplify `changedEvent` function

```js
function onChange(event)
{
   props.setTheme(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: its still not working